# Deserialization in F# vs. C#

Tags: c#, f#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-11-07T00:23:52.095Z",
      "symbol": "XBTUSD",
      "side": "Buy",
      "size": 1,
      "price": 9356.5,
      "tickDirection": "PlusTick",
      "trdMatchID": "01476235-ad89-1777-9067-8ce6d0e29992",
      "grossValue": 10688,
      "homeNotional": 0.00010688,
      "foreignNotional": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The last 3 fields are optional.

When I deserialize it in C#, I do the following:

```
public class Trade
{
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public string Symbol;
    public string Side;
    public long Size;
    public long Price;
    public long? GrossValue;
    public float? HomeNotional;
    public float? ForeignNotional;
}

public class TradeContainer
{
    public Trade[] Data;
}

var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeContainer>(x);
```

and it's all good.

In F#, I do this:

```
type Trade =
    {
        Timestamp : DateTime
        Symbol : string
        Side : string
        Size : int64
        Price : int64
        GrossValue : int64 option
        HomeNotional : float option
        ForeignNotional : float option
    }

type TradeContainer =
    {
        Data : Trade[]
    }

let t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeContainer>(x)
```

but it will fail. However, if I remove the option keyword, in the Trade type, then it deserializes properly.

The error I get is:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected property
>   'homeNotional' found when reading union. Path 'data[0].homeNotional',
>   line 1, position 233.   at at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DiscriminatedUnionConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer
>   serializer)

Why the difference? but also how can I achieve this since I need to plan that some values may not be present?

Comment: Option isn't the same thing as as Nullable<T>, which means the two classes are different. C# won't get discriminated unions until C# 9. In fact, the error shows that JSON.NET has explicit support for discriminated unions through the [DiscriminatedUnionConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DiscriminatedUnionConverter.htm) class and didn't like *the name* it found

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I need to know if these fields were present, or not, in the message I receive

Comment: Actually, `Option<T>` for missing JSON properties in C# would be very useful. An attribute can have an explicit `null` value but what about missing properties? Do we need to differentiate them or not? Never mind the nullable reference types that making nulls in C# a nuisance (which is good)

Comment: The problem is in JSON.NET's implementation of DU serialization. [It's not idiomatic](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support) and not what one would expect nowadays. It emits a `Case` property that describes the case of the attribute and an array of fields. Isaac Abraham [created an idiomatic custom converter](https://gist.github.com/isaacabraham/ba679f285bfd15d2f53e) that should be used instead

Comment: If you declare the fields using Nullable instead of option, then they will be null if they are missing in the json. You can declare types just for reading, and then after reading you can map to other types that use option.

Comment: @BentTranberg yes, it can be a workaround

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in JSON.NET's implementation of DU serialization. [It's not idiomatic](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support) and essentially dumps the case and fields :

```
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of width : float * length : float
    | Circle of radius : float
    | Empty

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let shape1 = Rectangle(1.3, 10.0)

    let json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shape1)
    // {
    //   "Case": "Rectangle",
    //   "Fields": [
    //     1.3,
    //     10.0
    //   ]
    // }
```

The deserializer expects the same structure.

Isaac Abraham created [an idiomatic custom converter](https://gist.github.com/isaacabraham/ba679f285bfd15d2f53e) that should be used instead :

```
let settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
settings.Converters.Add(IdiomaticDuConverter())

let t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeContainer>(json,settings)
```

`IdiomaticDuConverter`'s code is :

```
namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Converters

open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open Newtonsoft.Json
open System

type IdiomaticDuConverter() = 
    inherit JsonConverter()

    [<Literal>]
    let discriminator = "__Case"
    let primitives = Set [ JsonToken.Boolean; JsonToken.Date; JsonToken.Float; JsonToken.Integer; JsonToken.Null; JsonToken.String ]

    let writeValue (value:obj) (serializer:JsonSerializer, writer : JsonWriter) =
        if value.GetType().IsPrimitive then writer.WriteValue value
        else serializer.Serialize(writer, value)

    let writeProperties (fields : obj array) (serializer:JsonSerializer, writer : JsonWriter) = 
        fields |> Array.iteri (fun index value -> 
                      writer.WritePropertyName(sprintf "Item%d" index)
                      (serializer, writer) |> writeValue value)

    let writeDiscriminator (name : string) (writer : JsonWriter) = 
        writer.WritePropertyName discriminator
        writer.WriteValue name

    override __.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) = 
        let unionCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(value.GetType())
        let unionType = value.GetType()
        let case, fields = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(value, unionType)
        let allCasesHaveValues = unionCases |> Seq.forall (fun c -> c.GetFields() |> Seq.length > 0)

        match unionCases.Length, fields, allCasesHaveValues with
        | 2, [||], false -> writer.WriteNull()
        | 1, [| singleValue |], _
        | 2, [| singleValue |], false -> (serializer, writer) |> writeValue singleValue
        | 1, fields, _
        | 2, fields, false -> 
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            (serializer, writer) |> writeProperties fields
            writer.WriteEndObject()
        | _ -> 
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer |> writeDiscriminator case.Name
            (serializer, writer) |> writeProperties fields
            writer.WriteEndObject()

    override __.ReadJson(reader, destinationType, _, _) = 
        let parts = 
            if reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.StartObject then [| (JsonToken.Undefined, obj()), (reader.TokenType, reader.Value) |]
            else 
                seq { 
                    yield! reader |> Seq.unfold (fun reader -> 
                                         if reader.Read() then Some((reader.TokenType, reader.Value), reader)
                                         else None)
                }
                |> Seq.takeWhile(fun (token, _) -> token <> JsonToken.EndObject)
                |> Seq.pairwise
                |> Seq.mapi (fun id value -> id, value)
                |> Seq.filter (fun (id, _) -> id % 2 = 0)
                |> Seq.map snd
                |> Seq.toArray

        let values = 
            parts
            |> Seq.filter (fun ((_, keyValue), _) -> keyValue <> (discriminator :> obj))
            |> Seq.map snd
            |> Seq.filter (fun (valueToken, _) -> primitives.Contains valueToken)
            |> Seq.map snd
            |> Seq.toArray

        let case = 
            let unionCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(destinationType)
            let unionCase =
                parts
                |> Seq.tryFind (fun ((_,keyValue), _) -> keyValue = (discriminator :> obj))
                |> Option.map (snd >> snd)
            match unionCase with
            | Some case -> unionCases |> Array.find (fun f -> f.Name :> obj = case)
            | None ->
                // implied union case
                match values with
                | [| null |] -> unionCases |> Array.find(fun c -> c.GetFields().Length = 0)
                | _ -> unionCases |> Array.find(fun c -> c.GetFields().Length > 0)

        let values = 
            case.GetFields()
            |> Seq.zip values
            |> Seq.map (fun (value, propertyInfo) -> Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            |> Seq.toArray

        FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, values)

    override __.CanConvert(objectType) =
        FSharpType.IsUnion objectType &&
        not (objectType.IsGenericType &&
             typedefof<list<_>> = objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

Comment: I found that the code fails for enum options. I have added a new question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793576/deserializing-to-enum-option-in-f

Comment: Can you please briefly explain why DU deserialisation is kicking in? The question has no DU types but the error in the question and the solution you're pointing at fixes the issue via proper use of DUs. I cannot understand why record types end up being processed as DUs.