# Deserializing to enum option in F#

Tags: f#, json.net

A couple days ago, I posted a question about deserialization with enums in F#.
The question is here: [Deserialization in F# vs. C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748946/deserialization-in-f-vs-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment103788173_58748946)

The answer pointed to some code written by Isaac Abraham, at: https://gist.github.com/isaacabraham/ba679f285bfd15d2f53e

However I am facing another problem:

If the object to deserialize to has an object of type 'enum option', the deserialization will fail, whereas it'll work if the type is just 'enum'.

A minimal example:

```
type TestType =
    | A = 0
    | B = 1

type TestObjectA =
      {
           test : TestType
      }

type TestObjectB =
     {
         test : TestType option
     }


let x = "{\"test\":\"A\"}"
let TestA = Deserialize<TestObjectA> x // will work
let TestB = Deserialize<TestObjectB> x // will fail
```

and the large deserialization code is at: https://pastebin.com/95JZLa6j

I put the whole code in a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Vc0Rh
but it can't be run from there since the F# version they support will not accept the 'object' keyword.

So, my question is: why can't I use the option type on an enum, but it works on other types? As a side note, since I'm quite new to F#, I'm not fully understanding Isaac's code, although I spent some time going through it and trying to troubleshoot it.

My understanding is that this line:
                |> Seq.map (fun (value, propertyInfo) -> Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType))

will try to convert the type to the right enum, but not to the enum option.

As a bonus question, is there a working solution that does full idiomatic deserialization with enums? (without going through null types)

Comment: "since I'm quite new to F#, I'm not fully understanding Isaac's code". This type of code will be very non-standard because it involves reflection. (De)serialize<'T> will reflect on the form of 'T and apply various conventions to serialize and serialize objects. You can also use a manual approach which takes the string, makes a JsonObject, and gets the properties from there.

Comment: unfortunately, I have a large amount of classes I need to deal with (they're messages from a financial broker), and I need to find a way to deserialize them properly. At this stage, I'm thinking about doing a C# module to do the deserialization and pass back objects, but I'm really trying to do things in F#.

Comment: Without having studied the question in minute detail, I suspect you are trying to deserialize something that has been serialized as something else. If this data has been serialized as an enum (in C# or VB I'm guessing), then you cannot deserialize it as an enum option.

Comment: If my assumption above is correct, and the problem you are having is that the TestType enum may not be present in the json, and you need to detect that, then the only solution I can see is that you declare it as `Nullable<TestType>`. If not present at all, it will then be `null`. After deserialization you can then map the data to another record type where the field is an option rather than a nullable, so that you can take full advantage of F#.

Comment: It is possible that Newtonsoft.Json or other libraries has some tricks up their sleves for doing what you want, but do consider whether it's worth the effort and the risk. I suspect FsPickler (https://mbraceproject.github.io/FsPickler) can do pretty much whatever you want, but I've never used it like that.

Comment: @BentTranberg: the source jsons are simply missing some fields when they are not needed. Json.net deserializes that as 'Nullable<type>' and the code I posted can deserialize them as 'type option', but it can't do it when the type is an enum, whereas it does it with other types.

Comment: I can't make it work with int or string either. I get None if the field is not there, and the same exception as with an enum if the field is there. This is as expected because the field is not encoded as an F# option.

Comment: WIth Json.net, yes it fails. But with Isaac's code, it works with almost everything

Comment: I do not have this trouble using Newtonsoft as of today, though I did have it with the .Net serialization (also today). Maybe Newtsonsoft handles this situation now?

Answer (score 0):

```
open System.IO

type TestType =
    | A = 0
    | B = 1

type TestObjectB =
     {
         test : TestType option
     }

let jsonSerializeToString obj = 
    use writer = new StringWriter()
    let ser =  new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
    ser.Formatting <- Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    ser.Serialize(writer, obj)
    writer.ToString()

let jsonDeserializeFromString str =
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObjectB>(str)

let Test obj = 
    let str = jsonSerializeToString obj
    let obj' = jsonDeserializeFromString str
    obj'

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    { test = Some TestType.B } |> Test |> ignore
    { test = None } |> Test |> ignore
    0
```

Note: if you need to serialize a large collection of objects, then stream them to a file instead of an in-memory string to avoid an OutOfMemoryException. Like `use writer = File.CreateText(filePath)`.

Comment: By the way, I also tried the new .NET Core 3.0 built-in `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` for this, but it failed to deserialize the enum value properly. See my comment on the open issue at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38348#issuecomment-552546416

Comment: yes, I saw your comment. I guess the new json serializer is not ready yet.

Comment: the issue central to the question doesn't work with the code above: let t = jsonDeserializeFromString "{\"test\":\"A\"}" will crash

Comment: But why do you need it to work with that particular string instead of a string that works? (`"{\"test\":{\"Case\":\"Some\",\"Fields\":[1]}}"` or `"{\"test\":null}"`) What is the source of that string? Did it come from F#?

Comment: It's data I get from an trading platform, so I have no control over the json. I've just isolated the case that crashes when deserializing. They just don't put some values that are not needed sometimes. The original code I posted can map the null to an option, but fails for enum option, which I have quite a lot of. Since it's a bunch of different objects, I can't do case by case code with all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

> As a bonus question, is there a working solution that does full
>   idiomatic deserialization with enums?

I use the [Microsoft.FsharpLu.Json](https://github.com/Microsoft/fsharplu/wiki/fsharplu.json) package in production and find it works quite well for serializing and deserializing between "plain" javascript and idiomatic F#. Note `Microsoft.FsharpLu.Json` relies on `Newtonsoft.Json` under the hood.

Below is an example with your types and your test string, using [Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto) for tests.

```
namespace FsharpLuJsonTest

open Newtonsoft.Json
open Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json
open Expecto
open Expecto.Flip

// Setup for FSharpLu.Json
type JsonSettings =
    static member settings =
        let s = JsonSerializerSettings(
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore)
        s.Converters.Add(CompactUnionJsonConverter())
        s
    static member formatting = Formatting.None

type JsonSerializer = With<JsonSettings>

// Your example
type TestType =
    | A = 0
    | B = 1

type TestObjectA = { test : TestType }
type TestObjectB = { test : TestType option }

module Tests =

    let x = """{"test":"A"}"""

    [<Tests>]
    let tests =
        testList "Deserialization Tests" [
            testCase "To TestObjectA" <| fun _ ->
                JsonSerializer.deserialize x
                |> Expect.equal "" { TestObjectA.test = TestType.A }

            testCase "To TestObjectB" <| fun _ ->
                JsonSerializer.deserialize x
                |> Expect.equal "" { TestObjectB.test = Some TestType.A }
        ]

module Main =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args =
        runTestsInAssembly defaultConfig args
```

As you can see `FsharpLu.Json` supports Discriminated Unions and option types out of the box in the way you prefer. `FsharpLu.Json` is a less flexible solution than some others like [Chiron](https://xyncro.tech/chiron/) (which allow for much more customisation) but I tend to prefer the opinionated approach of `FsharpLu.Json`.

---

I haven't used it personally, but the new [FSharp.SystemText.Json](https://github.com/Tarmil/FSharp.SystemTextJson) library with the `JsonUnionEncoding.ExternalTag` setting should work roughly the same way `FsharpLu.Json` does. That library uses Microsoft's new `System.Text.Json` library under the hood rather than `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Comment: I will give it a try. The new Text.Json has issues with these types, it's not ready yet